# Is it possible to make an app without an activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-widget, android-service, broadcast

I want to make an app that will not have any activity. it can have  broadcast receiver and service and widget. Bocz when ever we create a project it asks for activity name

Comment: Yep! Very much possible. What else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said yourself, a widget and/or service are sufficient to create a valid application.

If your IDE or project wizard asks you for a mandatory activity name, you may delete this activity afterwards (along with its reference from the manifest), and you're done with it...